# how to create a file upload button in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend, expression-blend-3

Stupid question I know but how do i create one? All i need it to do is open up a dialog box and populate the text box next to it

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you are asking only about putting a user-selected filename into a TextBox control next to a button. You are NOT asking about the actual uploading of the file. If this is correct, then my answer is that you can do this:

```
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Multiselect = false;
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            yourTextBox.Text = dlg.File.Name;
            // Read stream of data from file, etc.
        }
```

You can't show the full path which would have been available via dlg.File.FullName due to security restrictions in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `OpenFileDialog` (silverlight 2.0). There are [plenty examples kicking around](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mamta_m/101232009104953AM/1.aspx) or I am a big fan of [Video Demo's](http://www.microsoft.com/video/en/us/details/4f14da66-e263-4ef2-8d42-f90dc4c00384) [example 2](http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/openfiledialog-and-file-upload/).